# How to Manage Sessions with ajax

Tags: php

Which are the common scenarios where both can not use together ?

Answer (score 5):

There is not much difference between AJAX requests and direct ones. Especially from the server-side point of view.

Your PHP script process a request and send out some data. It is really doesn't matter, who did that request - a browser itself or some JS object, running in the browser.

Frankly, AJAX just has nothing to do with sessions - it's PHP's realm

Answer (score 0):

If the call is through the same domain (example.com/index.php calls example.com/ajax.php) then it should be enough to call `session_start()` in both places and the user's session should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that all you script use the same domain, you can ensure that by positioning it before calling session_start :

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", example.tld)
```